# Gettext not working after rebooting

Tags: php, gettext

I'm using gettext in my webpage for the translations and the localization. Yesterday, it was working perfectly, and I shutted down the computer because I had to go to sleep... *(so normal! Hahahaha)*.

But now, today, when I turned on my computer, it seemed that gettext wasn't working, it was showing me the default language (English) instead of my desired language (Spanish), having all the translations in the right place. This is my gettext code:

```
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
    $domain = 'messages';
    $language = $lang;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8');
    putenv('LANGUAGE=' .$language);

    if( ENV != 'live' ){
        // reset caching nocache is a simlink to "."
        bindtextdomain($domain, dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Locale/nocache');
    }

    bindtextdomain($domain, dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Locale');
    bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
    textdomain($domain);
```

And this is what I have:
[image: My messages]

Also, in my $_SESSION['lang'] I have set the 'es_ES' string, so it would assign it to the Spanish language.
I also want to add that I use Ubuntu, with Apache, PHP and this things installed in it.
I tried restarting Apache but it didn't give any result.

What's happening to me? What can I do to repair it?
Thanks!

Comment: you are using `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8');` isn't it to be `es_ES`

Comment: @bansi  I don't think so... The last time it was working, I didn't change that...